# Subgraph of $K_n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Show that a subgraph induced by a nonempty subset of the vertex set of $K_n$ is a complete graph.

Let $W\subseteq V$ be an arbitrary subset of vertices of $K_n$. Let $H=(W,F)$ be the subgraph induced by $W$.

The hint says to change this into an *if-then* statement and perform a proof technique. Which I assume is a proof by induction.

Comment: You need to apply the definition of "complete graph" both to $K_n$ and to $H$.

Comment: That is just every vertex is adjacent/connected to every other vertex right? Given the number of vertices its $(n(n-1))/2$ to get the number of edges

Answer (score 1):

A (non-directed) graph $(V,E)$ is complete iff $\forall v_1, v_2 \in V: v_1 \neq v_2 \rightarrow \{v_1,v_2\} \in E$.

Now if we start with a complete graph $(V,E)$ and take some $W \subseteq V$, then the induced subgraph has edge set $E(W) := \{\{w_1, w_2\}: w_1 \neq w_2, w_1,w_2 \in W \} \cap E$, i.e. all edges in $E$ that have both endpoints in $W$.

Now try to show using the definition that $(W,E(W))$ is also complete.